# Cartopy and ECMWF data

Tags: python, python-xarray, cartopy

I downloaded data from the ECMWF Mars platform and I'm trying to render it using Cartopy. I read them with the xarray library and cfgrib engine.

```py
xarray.open_dataset(file.filepath, engine="cfgrib")
```

To render this data, I'm basically doing this:

```py
lons = value.longitude
lats = value.latitude
data = value.data

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(lons, lats) # I tried with xx,yy and lons, lats values
ax.contourf(xx, yy, data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ax.set_global()
```

But the result is quite disappointing.
[image: contourf representation]

I tried to use another function, result is not the same but still not what I'm expecting. Also, notice the weird size of the plot. I'm not using `plt.tight_layout()` function.

```py
lons = value.longitude
lats = value.latitude
data = value.data

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ax.set_global()
```

[image: pcolormesh representation]

Finally, I tried with an example I found here : https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/understanding_transform.html

```py
lon = np.linspace(0, 360, 25)
lat = np.linspace(30, 70, 25)
lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
data = np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2d) * 4) + np.sin(np.deg2rad(lon2d) * 4)
ax.contourf(lon, lat, data,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

This one is working when I use it directly in my code (just after the previous code).
[image: Example]

At this point, I'm quite lost. I tried different projection for the transform attribute, but only PlateCarree seems to work.

### Edit

My code is working correctly with another dataset.
[image: Temperature dataset]

I don't know the cause of the previous behaviour yet.

### Edit 2

The cause seems to be the irregular shape of the data mesh.
The issue I have with this data is that their are defined as 1D arrays (1D for lat, 1D for lon, 1D for data). I can display data by creating a regular mesh.

```py
            lons = value.longitude.data
            lats = value.latitude.data
            data = value.data

            # Just to adjuste the min and max of the normalizer
            print('Min value: ' + str(min(data)))
            print('Max value: ' + str(max(data)))

            # Previous tests
            # data, lons = cutil.add_cyclic_point(data, coord=lons)
            # xx, yy = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
            # ax.contourf(lons, lats, data, levels=100, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap=cmap, norm=normalizer)

            # Create grid values first.
            xi = np.linspace(min(lons), max(lons), 180)
            yi = np.linspace(min(lats), max(lats), 180)

            # Perform linear interpolation of the data (x,y)
            # on a grid defined by (xi,yi)
            triang = tri.Triangulation(lons, lats)
            interpolator = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang, data)
            Xi, Yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
            zi = interpolator(Xi, Yi)

            ax.contourf(Xi, Yi, zi, levels=100, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap=cmap, norm=normalizer)
```

Then, I got this plot. Their is still some work to do.
[image: Methan distribution]

Do you know a better way to process ? `value` is a `xarray.Dataset` object.
How to remove the white line at the position lon=0 ?

Comment: do you have a link to the data you're using ? We can't reproduce your problem without them

Comment: at least can you show the xarray metadata?

Comment: The data is coming from : https://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/cams-nrealtime/levtype=sfc/. I used the "Methane (chemistry)" dataset. The server seems to struggle this morning to execute requests.

I would like to test the code with other dataset.

Comment: I did some progress (see Edit 2). The cause seems to be the grid irregular shape.